# moving oldest files

Tags: file, vbscript

I was looking for a way to move the 5 oldest modified files in a folder to a different folder.
I came across some helpful pieces of code and I revised it to this:

```
Dim files
Dim startFolder
Dim destinationFolder
Dim oldestFile
Dim file
Dim FSO
startFolder = "C:\logs\current"
destinationFolder = "C:\logs\backup"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set files = FSO.GetFolder(StartFolder).files
Set oldFiles = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

If files.Count <= 5 Then
    WScript.Quit
End If

For i = 0 To 4
    Set files = FSO.GetFolder(StartFolder).files
    Set oldFiles = Nothing
    For Each file In files
       If Not IsObject(oldestFile) Then
           Set oldestFile = file
       Else
           If file.DateLastModified < oldestFile.DateLastModified Then
               Set oldestFile = file
           End If
       End If
    Next
    WScript.Echo "OLDEST: " & oldestFile.Name
    oldestFile.Move destinationFolder & "\" & oldestFile.Name
Next
```

Basically what it supposed to do is:

1. loop 5 times,
2. each time loop through the files and assign the oldest to `oldestFile`,
3. move the file to a different location.

However, it doesn't work, it's echoing the first file's name 5 times and move just this one.
I thought I should set the objects to `Nothing` to start fresh but to no avail.

Comment: There are so many of these types of questions already on [so]

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the variable `oldestFile` at the beginning (or end) of your loop, not the variable `oldFiles`.

```
For i = 0 To 4
    Set files = FSO.GetFolder(StartFolder).files
    Set oldestFile = Nothing
    For Each file In files
       ...
    Next
    WScript.Echo "OLDEST: " & oldestFile.Name
    oldestFile.Move destinationFolder & "\" & oldestFile.Name
Next
```

Otherwise the value of `oldestFile` will never change, because even after being moved the referenced file ramains the oldest file compared to the files in the source folder.